# CellClick not firing after RowValidating event fires in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` handling both the `CellClick` event and the `RowValidating` event.

When I click on a different row than the currently selected on, the Row Validating event fires. In the event, sometimes a pop-up is created with a yes/no option. However, when the pop-up appears the `CellClick` event handler is never reached, yet the Data Grid still updates the row.

And oddly enough when I step through the Debugger, the `CellClick` event never gets fired event whether the pop-up appeared or not.

Could it be the pop-up be causing the `CellClick` event from being fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So using a tracking tool, I seems as though the CellClick/CellContentClick event registered around the Same time as CellMouseUp. So the pop-up fired in Row Validating was essentially preventing the CellClick event from being handler

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if this is the answer without your source code, but it is possible you forgot to add the event handler. Do you have a line like this anywhere in your GUI?

```
button1.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(button1_CellClick);
```

Comment: I am handling both events, since the CellClick event fires when the pop-up is not created